# Acceder a una variable en plantilla de Django teniendo su nombre en string

Tags: python, django

```
{% for x in array%}
   {% for y in x %}
      <h1>{{y}}</h1>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Siendo `x` en el segundo `for` la clave de un diccionario que tiene como valor un array, y `x` en el primer `for` un `string` cuyo valor es la `x` del segundo `for`

¿Cómo se podría hacer para que coja el valor de la segunda `x` teniendo su nombre como string?

Comment: ¿`array` es una lista de diccionarios? ¿Todos los diccionarios de `array` tienen el mismo conjunto de `clave: valor`? Ojalá pudieras agregar a tu pregunta un __[mcve]__ para comprender mejor que quieres hacer.

Comment: `array` es un array de strings. Y lo que quiero es que teniendo el string `x` en el primer `for` cuyo valor es, por ejemplo, pepe, acceder a una variable que se llame pepe en el segundo for. @toledano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo que hagas un [filtro personalizado](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters). Crea un módulo en tu app que se llame `templatetags` y dentro un archivo para tus filtros y etiquetas personalizados, como lo indica la documentación.

En tu archivo de filtros agrega este código:

```
@register.filter(name='clave')
def clave(dicc, key):
    try: return dicc[key]
    except KeyError: return 0
```

El filtro actúa sobre tu diccionario y `clave` es la clave. Como no proporcionas un [**ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) te pongo un ejemplo genérico.

```
{% for nombre in nombres %}
   Diccionario: {{ dicc | clave: nombre }}
{% endfor %}
```

Como cualquier filtro en Django, puedes anidarlos y usarlo con otros filtros, por ejemplo, yo lo uso así:

```
{{pivot|clave:t|clave:'mini'|money}}
```

Para convertir esto:

```
{'ejer': Decimal('152675.00'),
 'label': 'January de 2014',
 'mini': Decimal('159793.56'),
 'porc': '95.55',
 'rein': Decimal('0.00'),
 'sald': Decimal('7118.56')}
```

en algo como esto:

[image: Captura de pantalla del uso del fitro <code>clave</code>]

Comment: Vale gracias, lo probaré cuando vuelva a esa parte.